# Annotation to join columns with OR condition instead of AND condition

Tags: java, hibernate, joincolumn, or-condition

I have 2 java classes, `Relation` and `Person`, which both are present in my database.

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "slave_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "master_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    })
    private List<Relation> relations;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relations")
public class Relation {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int child_id;

    @Column
    private int parent_id;

    @Column
    private String type;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Each Person has a list of relations (or not), the relation should be added to the list when the child_id or the parent_id of the relation is equal to the id of the person.

TL;DR:
When `relation.child_id OR relation.parent_id = person.id` => add relation to list of relations to the person

The issue I am facing is that this annotation:

```
@JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        })
```

creates following SQL (just the necessary part):

```
relations relations6_ 
            on this_.id=relations6_.slave_id 
            and this_.id=relations6_.master_id
```

What is the correct annotation in Java Hibernate to generate an SQL statement saying **OR** instead of **AND**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the options that you could utilize:

1. Database views. Create the view that does custom join for you and map the entity to the view.
2. [Join formula](http://hedleyproctor.com/2014/04/bespoke-join-conditions-with-hibernate-joinformula/). I managed to make them work only on many-to-one associations. Nevertheless, you could make the association bidirectional and apply the formula in the `Relation` entity.
3. [`@Subselect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975752/how-to-use-hibernate-subselect). This is a kind of Hibernate view, suitable if you can't afford to create a real database view or change the db schema to better suit the entity model structure.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027714/4754790) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049855/4754790) answer could also be helpful.

Also, you can always use two separate associations for slaves and masters:

```
public class Person {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "slave_id"),
    private List<Relation> slaves;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "master_id"),
    private List<Relation> masters;

    public List<Relation> getRelations() {
        List<Relation> result = new ArrayList<>(slaves);
        result.addAll(masters);
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, keep in mind that joining all of them in a single query requires full Cartesian product between masters and slaves.

Comment: Both Join formula and Subselect seem promising. But I rather not like to write SQL in these annotations, so I keep looking for an answer that suits this question.

Comment: @STheFox In that case, please see my updated answer. Anyway, there is no annotation specifically designed for your case; you'll have to use some workarounds.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fetch 2 lists, but I was looking to write better and cleaner code. My code was similar to your code. Isn't there an annotation to do this at once?

Comment: @STheFox No, there isn't any such annotation.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `@FilterDef` and `@Filter` annotations.